# How to separate images in the Android drawable file

Tags: android, android-drawable

I use a lot of images in my app, but the amount of PNG files that show up in the drawable section is a bit too much sometimes. Is there a way I can create multiple files in the drawable folder? Or some way to be able to divide the images?

I tried to click on the drawable folder and create a new Sample Data Directory, but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, you can't. Use `prefix_` to group alphabetically, and you can use vector drawables to have only one version of each image. You can also separate your app into multiple modules, which will each have a separate `res` folder.

Comment: No way to divide but if you have different sizes images then you can create folder like drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi and add your different sizes images inside it. same image with different sizes. check this video for understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUs9MK1uJ3Y